# Fixing ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, limit, file-descriptors, ulimit

I tested this on different GNU/Linux installations:

```
perl -e 'while(1){open($a{$b++}, "<" ,"/dev/null") or die $b;print " $b"}'
```

**System A and D**

The first limit I hit is 1024. It is easily raised by putting this into /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*                hard    nofile          1048576
```

and then run:

```
ulimit -n 1048576
echo 99999999 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Now the test goes to 1048576.

However, it seems I cannot raise it above 1048576. If I put 1048577 in limits.conf it is simply ignored.

What is causing that?

**System B**

On system B I cannot even get to 1048576:

```
echo 99999999 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

/etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*                hard    nofile          1048576
```

Here I get:

```
$ ulimit -n 65537
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
$ ulimit -n 65536
#OK
```

Where did that limit come from?

**System C**

This system also has the 1048576 limit in limits.conf and 99999999 in /proc/sys/fs/file-max.

But here the limit is 4096:

```
$ ulimit -n 4097
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
$ ulimit -n 4096
# OK
```

How do I raise that to (at least) 1048576?

(Note to self: Don't do: `echo 18446744073709551616 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max`)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, the limit seems to be 1048576. If I go over I get the following error: bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Comment: Hi, I am having a very similar problem. I think it would be very helpful to provide more details on what these different systems are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` contains:

```
UsePAM=yes
```

and that `/etc/pam.d/sshd` contains:

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

In the comment below @venimus states the 1M limit is hardcoded:

> The kernel 2.6.x source states ./fs/file.c:30:int sysctl_nr_open __read_mostly = 1024*1024; which is 1048676

The 1048576 is per process. So by having multiple processes this limit can be overcome.

Comment: If this was really the solution to your own problem, I think it'd be good to draw more of a connection between the problem and the above solution.

Comment: Re: 1048576 (= 2^10 * 2^10 = 1024^2, for reference). There may be some relevant information in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213069/2320823

Comment: What's ssh got to do with it?

Comment: I agree with @Linas . Sorry, I think the link between the answer and the question is unclear.

Comment: if you are interactions over ssh pam limits need to set the pam module for ssh to include the limits file otherwise activity over ssh will not work

Comment: The kernel 2.6.x source states `./fs/file.c:30:int sysctl_nr_open __read_mostly = 1024*1024;` which is 1048676 (hardcoded)