# Cannot increase maximum open files for redis

Tags: linux, apt, software-installation, redis

I am using ubunto 18.04, When i run `redis-server` on the terminal it says

```
# oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
# Redis version=4.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=11260, just started
# Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
# You requested maxclients of 10000 requiring at least 10032 max file descriptors.
# Server can't set maximum open files to 10032 because of OS error: Operation not permitted.
# Current maximum open files is 1022. maxclients has been reduced to 990 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
# Creating Server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
```

I tried to increase this limit before by running

```
ulimit -n 10240
```

But it resulted in following error

```
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

Then I tried to lower its value by running `ulimit -n 1022` and it surprisingly ran successfully and decreased that limit.

I then followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux), but after doing `echo 800000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max` overrides the "file-max" file but do not actually change max file limit

```
$ ulimit -n 
1022
```

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359189/fixing-ulimit-open-files-cannot-modify-limit-operation-not-permitted?newreg=09adaf9119b24db493d9394dbabfbc29) I found another related question and my case seem to be **System C** one. I tried doing the following.

1) I added the following lines in my `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
* soft nofile 4096
* hard nofile 10240
```

2) Added the following line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

```
UsePAM=yes
```

3) Added the follwing in '/etc/pam.d/sshd' file

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

But still no effect. `ulimit -n` command still shows 1022.

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1) also seems informative but is of no use. I am unable to update my per process file limit.

Comment: (1) Have you read documentation on `ulimit`?  Like the part about not being able to increase the hard limit, or raise the soft limit above the hard limit, unless you’re root?  You show a `ulimit` command with a `$` prompt.  Are you running as root? (2) Did you reboot after editing the `/etc` files? (3) Did you try raising your limit (by typing `ulimit -n` followed by a number) after you edited the `limits.conf` file? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.